# python regex named captured group with specific terminating substrings

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a python regex that splits a line of text into firstname, lastname, employer, street address,city,state, country, income and bonus as follows:

```
myreg=re.compile(r'\'(?P<first_name>.*)\',\'(?P<last_name>.*)\',\'(?P<employer>.*)\',\'(?P<street_address>.*)\',\'(?P<city>.*)\',\'(?P<state>.*)\',\'(?P<country>[A-Z]{2})?\',\'(?P<phone>[\d\+\-]*)\',\'(?P<email>[A-Za-z0-9\@\-\_\.]*)\',\'(?P<income>[\d\.]*)\',\'(?P<bonus>[\d\.]*)\'')
m=myreg.search(line)
print(m.groupdict())
```

This works fine if the input line is:

> 'john','doe','searchers','some street','some city','some
> state','HE','000-00-00','missing@123.abc','0.00','0'

Output is:

> {'first_name': 'john', 'last_name': 'doe', 'employer': 'searchers',
> 'street_address': 'some street', 'city': 'some city', 'state': 'some
> state', 'country': 'HE', 'phone': '000-00-00', 'email':
> 'missing@123.abc', 'income': '0.00', 'bonus': '0'}

However, things don't work if a line has empty fields such as:

> '','','testemployer','','','a very long city's
> nameaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','','HE','','','',''

For the above, the output becomes:

> {'first_name': "','", 'last_name': 'testemployer', 'employer': '',
> 'street_address': '', 'city': "a very long city's nameaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
> 'state': '', 'country': 'HE', 'phone': '', 'email': '', 'income': '',
> 'bonus': ''}

I tried setting the names as [^']*, but some names have apostrophes, and some employers can contain apostrophes and commas such as "O'Toole, McGyver and Scrooge Law".  However, from the data I saw, fields are definitely separated by "','". Given this, is there a way to have a regex pattern that would ensure that the captured groups do not contain "','"?

Comment: Is the data from a csv file?  If it is, using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from the standard library might be a better way to parse the data.

Comment: unfortunately, no.  The data has been extracted from a much bigger file using an earlier regex.  I was actually thinking of doing something similar like writing the extracted lines to a separate csv and then parsing them using the csv module.  However, the original file is already very large, and the generated csv will still be large.  Currently disk space will be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a *very* long time on what I thought would be a correct regex, but I still could not get it to correctly process accept your string:

```
'','','testemployer','','','a very long city's nameaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','','HE','','','',''
```

And then it dawned upon me that it appears you have an extra empty field before the city field (i.e. there should only be one field, the `street_address`, between the `employer` and `city` fields but you seem to have two. **If this is truly how the data appears, then there is nothing I can do about it. But if you just made an error in copying the the problematic input, then ...**

First of all, I have used a double-quote (") to code your regex string. This removes the necessity of having to escape all those single quote characters. There is also no need to escape special characters such as *+*, *-* and *-* when they appear within character class specifications. Finally, I have replaced *\d* with [0-9], which is different when you are dealing with Unicode. The former includes many values from languages that you might not find on telephones or currencies that you are interested in, such as ०१२३४५६७८९. But if you need *\d* instead of the usual digit 0 .. 9, then please just revert back.

Anyway, to handle the city field and fields like it that might have an embedded quote character, the way I have handled it is to use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
'(?P<field_name>(?:[^']|'(?!,))*)'
```

1. `'` - Matches a quote.
2. `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group.
3. `[^']` - Matches any non-quote character.
4. `|` - or
5. `'(?!,)` - Matches a quote if the next character is not a comma. In other words match a quote if this does not appear to be the closing quote that describes a field.
6. `)` - End of the non-capturing group.
7. `*` - Matches 0 or more characters defined by items 2 through 6 above.
8. `'` - Matches a quote.

The code:

```python
import re

lines = [
    "'john','doe','searchers','some street','some city','some state','HE','000-00-00','missing@123.abc','0.00','0'",
    "'','','testemployer','','a very long city's nameaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','','HE','','','',''"
    ]

myreg = re.compile(r"'(?P<first_name>(?:[^']|'(?!,))*)','(?P<last_name>(?:[^']|'(?!,))*)','(?P<employer>(?:[^']|'(?!,))*)','(?P<street_address>(?:[^']|'(?!,))*)','(?P<city>(?:[^']|'(?!,))*)','(?P<state>(?:[^']|'(?!,))*)','(?P<country>[A-Z]{2})?','(?P<phone>[0-9+-]*)','(?P<email>[A-Za-z0-9\@\-\_\.]*)','(?P<income>[0-9.]*)','(?P<bonus>[0-9.]*)'")
for line in lines:
    m = myreg.search(line)
    print(line)
    for k, v in m.groupdict().items():
        print (f'{k} -> {v}')
    print()
```

Prints:

```
'john','doe','searchers','some street','some city','some state','HE','000-00-00','missing@123.abc','0.00','0'
first_name -> john
last_name -> doe
employer -> searchers
street_address -> some street
city -> some city
state -> some state
country -> HE
phone -> 000-00-00
email -> missing@123.abc
income -> 0.00
bonus -> 0

'','','testemployer','','a very long city's nameaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','','HE','','','',''
first_name ->
last_name ->
employer -> testemployer
street_address ->
city -> a very long city's nameaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
state ->
country -> HE
phone ->
email ->
income ->
bonus ->
```